# removing leaf from memsql cluster leads to slave partitions

Tags: singlestore

After removing a leaf from the memsql cluster i ended up having 2 slave partitions that are blocking the functionality of my cluster right now.

ERROR 1777 (HY000) at line 1: Partition <>:<> has no master instance.

I was reading that slave partitions can appear only in replication - 2 , however i have replication -1 .

Also what is the step to follow from here? Promoting partition does not work .

Comment: PROMOTE PARTITION WITH DROP |       6 | ip |        3306 |     1 | failed (Partition `_6`:6 is provisioning replication and can't be promoted to master)   |          273 |
| PROMOTE PARTITION WITH DROP |      36 | ip |        3306 |     1 | failed (Partition `_36`:36 is provisioning replication and can't be promoted to master) |          289 |

Comment: Jump onto our public slack channel and we'll help you debug it: http://chat.memsql.com/